# Get parameter values of a URL in a string variable PHP

Tags: php, parsing, query-string

I have this url in a string. This is not the current page URL, but it's in a string store for me to access.

```
$query_string = 'Itemid=364&option=com_easyblog&id=2&view=entry';
```

I know we can use `$_GET["fname"]` to get the valued of `option` and `id` etc if it's in the URL. But I don't know how to look for the `option` value if the url is in a string.

I tried `strpos($query_string, 'com_easyblog') != FALSE` to see if `com_easyblog` exists in the URL, it works fine. But When it come to checking the `id` I'm stuck. Can you guys help?

Comment: Try [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 2):

You want to parse query string ([parse_str function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php))